# How to slice lists in Python

Tags: python, pandas, split, data-cleaning

I am at the trying to clean some data for a log regression in python  and my list keeps showing up like

```
loansData['FICO.Score'][0:5]
Out[23]: 
81174    735-739
99592    715-719
80059    690-694
15825    695-699
33182    695-699
```

I want to be able to pick the lower fico range number how do I remove the first set of numbers and also remove the upper range?

Comment: Example of input data would be useful.

Comment: And example output..

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like your Q's subject is germane to what you're actually asking about -- you're doing fine with the slicing of that one list, now what you have are, instead, **strings** (each an item from said list).

Anyway, assuming e.g the first one is `81174    735-739` (exactly four spaces in the middle, none before, no tab, &c), the `735` is the **string** slice at [9:12].  So for example

```
[s[9:12] for s in loansData['FICO.Score'][0:5]]
```

should show what you want (could easily need tweaking by 1 or so if the hypotheses above about the extract string format are incorrect, but, that's the general idea).

Answer (score 0):

This is in example that would subset your data to only include FICO observations w/ '695-699', ' 690-694' scores.

```
loansData['FICO.Score'][loansData['FICO.Score'].isin(['695-699', ' 690-694'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes the 5 digit number is the series index, and you want to return an array with the lower bound of each value.

```
import pandas as pd
```

data:

```
i=[81174,99592,80059,15825,33182]
d = ['735-739','715-719','690-694','695-699','695-699']
```

recreate frame:

```
df =pd.DataFrame(d, index=i, columns=['FICO.Score'])
```

slice string and convert to int:

```
df['FICO.Score'].apply(lambda x: int(x[:-4])).values
```

Calling values returns and array from the series(getting rid of the index)